# select() always returns 1; TCP connected socket troubles in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, select, pthreads

I'm doing a c++ project that requires a server to create a new thread to handle connections each time accept() returns a new socket descriptor. I am using select to decide when a connection attempt has taken place as well as when a client has sent data over the newly created client socket (the one that accept creates). So two functions and two selects - one for polling the socket dedicated to listening for connections, one for polling the socket created when a new connection is successful.

The behavior of the first case is what I expect - FD_ISSET returns true for the id of my listening socket only when a connection is requested, and is false until the next connection attempt. The second case does not work, even though the code is exactly the same with different fd_set and socket objects. I'm wondering if this stems from the TCP socket? Do these sockets always return true when polled by a select due to their streamy nature?

```
//working snippet

struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 500000;
fd_set readfds;
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(sid,&readfds);

//start server loop
for(;;){

    //check if listening socket has any client requrests, timeout at 500 ms
    int numsockets = select(sid+1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,&tv);
    if(numsockets == -1){
        if(errno == 4){
            printf("SIGINT recieved in select\n");
            FD_ZERO(&readfds);
            myhandler(SIGINT);
        }else{
            perror("server select");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    //check if listening socket is ready to be read after select returns
    if(FD_ISSET(sid, &readfds)){
        int newsocketfd = accept(sid, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrsize);
        if(newsocketfd == -1){
            if(errno == 4){
                printf("SIGINT recieved in accept\n");
                myhandler(SIGINT);
            }else{
                perror("server accept");
                exit(1);
            }
        }else{
            s->forkThreadForClient(newsocketfd);
        }
    } 






//non working snippet

//setup clients socket with select functionality
struct timeval ctv;
ctv.tv_sec = 0;
ctv.tv_usec = 500000;
fd_set creadfds;
FD_ZERO(&creadfds);
FD_SET(csid,&creadfds);



for(;;){

    //check if listening socket has any client requrests, timeout at 500 ms
    int numsockets = select(csid+1,&creadfds,NULL,NULL,&ctv);
    if(numsockets == -1){
        if(errno == 4){
            printf("SIGINT recieved in client select\n");
            FD_ZERO(&creadfds);
            myhandler(SIGINT);
        }else{
            perror("server select");
            exit(1);
        }
    }else{
        printf("Select returned %i\n",numsockets);
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(csid,&creadfds)){


        //read header
        unsigned char header[11];
        for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
            if(recv(csid, rubyte, 1, 0) != 0){
                printf("Received %X from client\n",*rubyte);
                header[i] = *rubyte;
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Thanks for the responses, but I don't believe it has much todo with the timeout value being inside the loop. I tested it and even with tv being reset and the fd_set being zeroed every time the server loops, select still returns 1 immediately. I feel like there's a problem with how select is treating my TCP socket. Any time I set selects highest socket id to encompass my TCP socket, it returns immediately with that socket set. Also, client does not send anything, just connects.

Comment: Could you fix your indenting so it looks right? It's really hard to follow with all the code smushed up against the left margin like that.

Comment: You say it doesn't work. But what does it do instead ?

Comment: I can attest that `select()` works fine for TCP sockets, so there must be a bug in your code.  From what you have pasted, perhaps `csid` is not set to the value that you think it is?

Comment: By the way, thread creation is not particularly cheap so we typically use a pool for work like this rather than spawning a new thread for every single connection on demand

Comment: You are ignoring errors when receiving, and you are also ignoring end of stream `recv()` returns zero. You need to *close the socket* in both cases. This is why `select()` keeps returning 1: it is telling you to read the socket because there is an EOS pending, which you are ignoring, so it tells you again.

Answer (score 6):

One thing you *must* do is reset the value of `tv` to your desired timeout every time before you call `select()`. The `select()` function changes the values in `tv` to indicate how much time is left in the timeout, after returning from the function. If you fail to do this, your `select()` calls will end up using a timeout of zero, which is not efficient.

Some other operating systems implement `select()` differently, in such a way that they don't change the value of `tv`. Linux does change it, so you must reset it.

Answer (score 3):

Move

```
 FD_ZERO(&creadfds); 
 FD_SET(csid,&creadfds);
```

into the loop. The function `select()` reports the result in this structure. You already retrieve the result with

```
FD_ISSET(csid,&creadfds);
```